# Wire 5 vibration motors on one switch

Tags: circuit-design, wiring, basic

I am trying to run five vibration motors rated at 3.7 volts each on one switch. The power will come from a 12V, 40 Amp relay on my Jeep (SPOD). How can I wire the motors all together to turn on at one time. I have no experience with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use an adjustable switching voltage regulator like this one:

https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B00C4QVTNU/

Wire it like this: Switch -> Regulator -> All your motors in parallel.

Check the vibration motors current rating. Then multiply it by 5 (the number of motors). That's how much current the regulator needs to supply. The reg I linked says it's good for 8 amps. There are bigger and smaller ones available on amazon.

Lastly, make sure you set the reg to the right voltage before you hook up the motors. If you don't get one with a display, just put a voltmeter on the output and turn the adjustment screw until the voltage reads 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how much current they take, due to your odd number, the simplest solution is using a 12V to 5V regulator, like a USB car charger, and wire them all in parallel. Ex:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQMxEm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

They should be fine at 5V. If not, bring it down some more. 1 or 2 1N400x diodes would be fine (5 - 0.7 = 4.3V, 5 - 1.4 = 3.6V). Or modify the car usb charger to be 3.7V.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my answer. Five 3.7 volt vibration motors.

Comment: Or select a regulator with the desired voltage.  If power saving is a concern then a small switching regulator is an option.